# How to check greyout link by checking two conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

May I know how to greyed out a link in a row that has event status which is over and the date of the event is less than 90 days? This will result that the booking cannot be cancel. I got the coding but the result is not showing correctly.

```
<?php if (($row['Event_status']== 'Ongoing') OR ( strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime('-90 day' ) )) {                                              
echo "<td><a href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</a></td>";} ?>
```

Comment: So basically if the event is 90 days away or less you won't be able to cancel it? What you need to check the status for?

Comment: if you found the solution  from our posts please up vote and check the best solution so everybody will be happy about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<td>
    <?php if (($row['Event_status'] == 'Ongoing') OR (strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime('-90 day'))) { ?>
        <span class="grey-out">Too late to cancel</span>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="CustPortal.php?booking_id=<?= $row['Booking_id']; ?>">Cancel</a>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

not clear from the question but I assume you want something like that

```
 <?php
  if (($row['Event_status']== 'Ongoing') OR ( strtotime($row['Date']) > strtotime('-90 day' ) )) 
  {                                              
  echo "<td><a href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</a></td>";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "<td><span style='color:grey;'> ".strtotime($row['Date'])." </span></td>";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Why have a link at all if it can't be clicked?

Comment: so that I don want it to be cancel. jus display for information